# Calculate the Number of Patients Being Treated In a Given Hour

Tags: sas

I'd like to calculate the number of patients currently within an Emergency Room by hour and I'm having trouble conceptualizing an efficient code.

I have two time variables, 'Check In Time' and 'Release Time'. These date/time variables are obviously arbitrary and the 'release time' variable will come after the 'check in time variable'.

I would like the output for a given day to look something like this:

```
    Hour        Midnight   1am   2am   3am    4am.....
    # of Pts      34       56     89    23     29
```

So for example, at 1am there were 56 patients currently in the ED -when considering both checkin and release times.

My initial thought is to:
1) round the time variables
2) Write a code a code the looks something like this...

```
  data EDTimesl;
  set  EDDATA;
  if checkin = '1am' and release = '2am' then OneAMToTwoAM = 1;
  if checkin = '1am' and release = '3am' then OneAMToTwoAM = 1;
  if checkin = '1am' and release = '3am' then TwoAMToThreeAM = 1;
  ....
  run;
```

This, however, gives me pause because I feel there is a more efficient method!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It depends on your input data but I highly suspect here are much easier ways. Show what your input data looks like and the structure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculating the Number of Patients in an ED by Hour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55924594/calculating-the-number-of-patients-in-an-ed-by-hour)

Comment: @SMor - I posted the same question twice but different tags, SAS and SQL Server

Comment: @Greg you modify the tags if necessary but reposting isn't appropriate.

Answer (score -1):

I found a code online that might answer the question! Please see below:

```
data have (keep=admitdate disdate);
   /* generate some admission and discharge date time variables*/
   year=2015; /* for example all of the admits are in 2015*/
   format admitdate disdate datetime20.;
   do day= 1 to 20;
   do month=1 to 12;
     hour = floor(24*ranuni(4445));
     min  = floor(50*ranuni(1234));
     date = mdy(month,day,2015);
     admitdate=dhms(date,hour,min,0);
     /* random duration of stay*/
     duration = 60 + floor(3000*ranuni(7777));
     disdate = intnx('minute',admitdate,duration);
     output;
     end;
     end;
     run;

data occupancy;
  set have;
  format admitdate disdate datetime20.;
  Do Occupanthour = (dhms(datepart(admitdate),hour(admitdate),0,0)) to 
  dhms(datepart(disdate),hour(disdate),0,0) by 3600;
  HourOfDay = hour(OccupantHour);
  DayOfWeek = Weekday(datepart(OccupantHour));
  output;
  end;
  format OccupantHour datetime20.;
  run;

  Proc freq data=occupancy;
  Tables HourOfDay;
  run;

 proc tabulate data=occupancy;
  class DayOfWeek;
  class HourOfDay;
  tables HourOfDay,
      (DayOfWeek All)*n;
 run;
```