# Calculating the Number of Patients in an ED by Hour

Tags: sql-server

I'd like to calculate the number or average(if average is possible) of patients currently within an Emergency Room by hour over a given time span (week or month or year)and I'm having trouble conceptualizing an efficient code (not just the number of registrations).

I have two time variables, 'Check In Time' and 'Release Time'. These date/time variables are obviously arbitrary and the 'release time' variable will come after the 'check in time variable'.

Example Data

```
 Patient_ID    'Check In Time'                 'Release Time'
 01           2015-08-01 02:49:00         2015-08-01 08:29:00
 02           2015-08-02 01:30:00         2015-08-02 14:29:00
 03           2015-08-02 21:30:00         2015-09-02 01:20:00
```

I would like the output for a given day to look something like this:

```
Hour        Midnight   1am   2am   3am    4am.....
# of Pts      34       56     89    23     29
```

So for example, at 1am there were 56 patients currently in the ED -when considering both checkin and release times.

My initial thought is to: 1) round the two variables 2) Write a code a code the looks something like this...

```
  select Pt_fin
  case when  checkin like '1am' and release like '2am' then '1' else '0' 
  end OneAMToTwoAM,
  case when  checkin like '1am' and release like '2am' then '1' else '0' 
  end OneAMToTwoAM,
  case when  checkin like '1am' and release like '2am' then '1' else '0' 
  end TowAMToThreeAM
  from ED
```

....

This, however, gives me pause because I feel there is a more efficient method!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which database are you using (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle)?  "SQL" is just a language, not an actual product.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Provide sample data and desired results.  And please convey that you are *NOT* using strings to represent times.

Comment: Thanks @TimBiegeleisen. I clarified that I am using SQL Server and added a snippet of example data. The desire results are also listed above.

Comment: Read about calendar tables.

Answer (score 0):

This could be solve your query, but the columns names must be with no empty spaces, try to change it!

```
select 
Patient_ID
,count(case when DATEPART(hh, 'Check In Time') >= 0 and DATEPART(hh,'Release Time')         <= 1 then 1 else 0 end) Midnight   
,count(case when DATEPART(hh, 'Check In Time') >= 1 and DATEPART(hh,'Release Time')     <= 2 then 1 else 0 end) 1AM   
,count(case when DATEPART(hh, 'Check In Time') >= 2 and DATEPART(hh,'Release Time')     <= 3 then 1 else 0 end) 2AM   
,count(case when DATEPART(hh, 'Check In Time') >= 3 and DATEPART(hh,'Release Time')     <= 4 then 1 else 0 end) 3AM   
from ED
group by Patient_ID
```

I hope this helps!